# Django - How to avoid using "request.META.HTTP_HOST" in a Django template?

Tags: django

I'm developing a website with Django. This is correct or I should avoid doing it in this way?

```
<img src="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}/media/assets/img/bike.gif">
```

I'm doing this because I have internationalization in this project and I translate also the url patterns.

There are other strategies to get the root url?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3):

It seems that since you are using the HTTP_HOST that user's browser sent, you can simply write it as

```
<img src="/media/assets/img/bike.gif">
```

and get the same result.

Comment: Seems it's all there is to it, the path will be relative to the current domain/subdomain, whether it's a translated domain name or not.